# Batch the Output of a TransformManyBlock in TPL Dataflow

Tags: c#, multithreading, dataflow, throttling, tpl-dataflow

Is there a way to limit the output queue of a `TranformManyBlock` in the TPL dataflow library?

I have a `TranformManyBlock` that takes a file as input and outputs a `MyObject` instance for each line in the file. The problem is there could be an unbounded number of lines in the file and it would be preferable to emit batches from a `TransformManyBlock` to process in the next block rather than load all of them into memory at once. It's almost like there needs to be a `TransformManyBatchBlock`.

Something like this:

```
var convertFileToObjects = new TransformManyBatchBlock<FileInfo, MyObject>((Post, file) =>
{
    foreach (var line in file)
    {
        Post(ConvertFileToMyObject(line));
    }
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions(){OutputBoundedCapacity = 1000});
```

Comment: Can you use Rx (System.Reactive)?

Comment: It looks like some of the transformation observables could be useful in this case. I may have to go that route since it doesn't look like dataflow supports this behavior with the default blocks.

Comment: That's the job of a BatchBlock. If you want to pause processing if a downlevel block gets flooded you should set the `BoundedCapacity` on all intermediate blocks, including the BatchBlock. If your `TransformManyBlock` uses an iterator method, that method will be blocked if downstream blocks are themselves blocked.

Comment: @Adam there's no reason to add Rx or Observables, the Dataflow library already provides backpressure, batching, grouping etc in ways that are *easier* to use in dataflow/pipeline scenarios than Rx.